# Mysql: Получить кол-во записей

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Имеется 2 таблицы MariaDB (Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)) :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`phone` int, `calldate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`phone`, `calldate`)
VALUES
    (123, '2020-01-01 10:00:00'),
    (123, '2020-01-01 11:00:00'),
    (123, '2020-01-01 12:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`phone` int, `calldate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`phone`, `calldate`)
VALUES
( 123, '2020-01-01 09:01:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 09:02:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:15:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:20:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:23:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:05:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:12:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:25:00')
;
```

Как получить следующий результат:
Поле calldate 1-ой записи из table1 (2020-01-01 10:00:00) более позднее чем поле calldate 2-х записей из table2.
Аналогично для 2-ой записи - кол-во записей равно 5  (с 09:01:00 по 10:23:00)
Но 2 записи из table2 с calldate 09:01:00 и 09:02:00 уже "перекрыты" 1-ой записью из table1, так что результат должен быть равен 3,а не 5.

```
|------+----------------------+-------+
| phone | calldate            | count |
|-------+---------------------+-------+
| 123   | 2020-01-01 09:02:00 | 2     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 10:23:00 | 3     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 11:25:00 | 3     |
|------+---------------------+|------+|
```

Также, calldate в результирующей наборе должен быть равен наболее позднему значению calldate из  "перекрытого" подмножества.

Версия MySQL не поддерживает window functions

Comment: Результирующая таблица не соответствует данным. например, в исходных данных нет времени `09:02:00`. результирующая таблица точно во всех строках `phone=123`.

Comment: Alex R, спасибо за замечание. Поправил

Answer (score 1):

На MariaDB не проверял, но на PostgreSQL работает (LIMIT на MariaDB есть)

```
select phone, max_date, count 
from (
  select t2.phone,max(t2.calldate) as max_date, count(*) as count,
  (select t1.calldate from table1 t1 where t1.phone = t2.phone and t1.calldate > t2.calldate order by t1.calldate limit 1) as t1_date
  from table2 t2
  group by t1_date, t2.phone
) as q
```